# How to open hyperlink with target="_blank" in PyQtWebEngine?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I have made a web browser using pyqt5 and PyQtWebEngine.It works fine but when I click on a hyperlink with target="_blank" then it does not work but how will I fix it. You can view its source code by clicking on this link https://github.com/SaptakBhoumik/WebPlus
. Please review my code and tell me what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes):

> _blank: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.

That is, the objective is not to reload the page but to create a new tab, and then to obtain that request you must override the createWindow method of QWebEngineView (or QWebEnginePage):

```py
from functools import cached_property
import sys


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class WebView(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def createWindow(self, type_):
        if not isinstance(self.window(), Browser):
            return

        if type_ == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            return self.window().tab_widget.create_tab()


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def create_tab(self):
        view = WebView()

        index = self.addTab(view, "(Untitled)")
        self.setTabIcon(index, view.icon())
        view.titleChanged.connect(
            lambda title, view=view: self.update_title(view, title)
        )
        view.iconChanged.connect(lambda icon, view=view: self.update_icon(view, icon))
        self.setCurrentWidget(view)
        return view

    def update_title(self, view, title):
        index = self.indexOf(view)
        self.setTabText(index, title)

    def update_icon(self, view, icon):
        index = self.indexOf(view)
        self.setTabIcon(index, icon)


class Browser(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        view = self.tab_widget.create_tab()
        view.load(
            QtCore.QUrl(
                "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target"
            )
        )

    @cached_property
    def tab_widget(self):
        return TabWidget()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Browser()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** I recommend that you review the official example: [WebEngine Widgets Simple Browser Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html), in addition to its implementation in [PySide2](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/webenginewidgets/tabbedbrowser?h=5.15.2) which is easily translatable to PyQt5 where this feature and many more are implemented.

Comment: Can you please review my code and tell me what to do. You can view its source code by clicking on this link https://github.com/SaptakBhoumik/WebPlus

Comment: @SaptakBhoumik No, I am not dedicated to implementing my solutions in projects (at least not in SO) so my answer is sufficient since it covers all the logic to be able to implement it